# Como alterar a versão do aplicativo no android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou prestes a lançar um aplicativo e sei que, em algum momento farei atualizações, porem não achei na ferramenta o local para alterar a versão do app, visto que é diferente do Eclipse ADT, que ficava no próprio androidmanifest. Alguém sabe como??

Answer (score 4):

No android studio dentro do ficheiro build.gradle você vai achar um código  que nem o que esta abaixo :

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

onde vem versionCode é normalmente o código utilizado internamente para aplicação para fazer uma comparação. Se você tiver uma base de dados, você pode utilizar esse código para actualizar as tabelas caso ele mude.
o versionName e o código visível para o utilizador.

Caso voce nao tenha esse bloco e so copiar e colar no se